# Api-platform 2.7 - Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type

Tags: php, api-platform.com, doctrine-odm

I'm facing a problem using Api-platform:2.7. Everything works fine in my application with PHP Attributes and APi resources. However, I find out that when I `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle`, all the POST resources become unusable. my application is using both an SQL and a Mongo database.

Removing the composer package fix the error.

This is the doctrine_mongodb.yaml I'm using (I tried with and without the auto_mapping. Same error)

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    auto_generate_hydrator_classes: true
    connections:
        default:
            server: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_URL)%'
            options: {}
    default_database: '%env(resolve:MONGODB_DB)%'
    document_managers:
        default:
            # auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: attribute
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Document'
                    prefix: 'App\Document'
                    alias: App
```

Here is the error stacktrace:

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Error",
  "@type": "hydra:Error",
  "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
  "hydra:description": "Unable to generate an IRI for the item of type \"App\\Entity\\TryingResource\"",
  "trace": [
    {
      "namespace": "",
      "short_class": "",
      "class": "",
      "type": "",
      "function": "",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php",
      "line": 177,
      "args": []
    },
    {
      "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Symfony\\Routing",
      "short_class": "IriConverter",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Symfony\\Routing\\IriConverter",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "getIriFromResource",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/EventListener/WriteListener.php",
      "line": 113,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "App\\Entity\\TryingResource"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "ApiPlatform\\Symfony\\EventListener",
      "short_class": "WriteListener",
      "class": "ApiPlatform\\Symfony\\EventListener\\WriteListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "onKernelView",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php",
      "line": 117,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ViewEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.view"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
      "short_class": "WrappedListener",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "__invoke",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 230,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ViewEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.view"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "callListeners",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 59,
      "args": [
        [
          "array",
          [
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ],
            [
              "object",
              "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\WrappedListener"
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.view"
        ],
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ViewEvent"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher",
      "short_class": "EventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "dispatch",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php",
      "line": 154,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ViewEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.view"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug",
      "short_class": "TraceableEventDispatcher",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\Debug\\TraceableEventDispatcher",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "dispatch",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 158,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Event\\ViewEvent"
        ],
        [
          "string",
          "kernel.view"
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handleRaw",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php",
      "line": 75,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
        ],
        [
          "integer",
          1
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "HttpKernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handle",
      "file": "/srv/api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php",
      "line": 202,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
        ],
        [
          "integer",
          1
        ],
        [
          "boolean",
          true
        ]
      ]
    },
    {
      "namespace": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel",
      "short_class": "Kernel",
      "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel",
      "type": "->",
      "function": "handle",
      "file": "/srv/api/public/index.php",
      "line": 28,
      "args": [
        [
          "object",
          "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Request"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from a bug in api-platform and it was not able to work with both ORM and ODM.

It relates to this issue : https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5020

Fix was made in this PR : https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/5032

Answer (score 0):

> Note: this answer is just the completion of [@Guaillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16937036/guillaume)'s answer

If you check Issue [`#5020`  by `Oskmoz`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/5020), you will see this was an issue that you can't use both ODM and ORM together.

this issue was solved on 30 Sep 2022 by [`soyuka` in pull request `#5032`](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/5033)  and they merged with their source code.

Just use `composer update`. it should be work.

#### what was the problem ?

if you check the [pull request's files](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/5032/files), you will see they used `PersistProcessor` and `RemoveProcessor` directly, `Soyuka` Just
changed it to something like this:

```php
'api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.remove_processor';
'api_platform.doctrine_mongodb.odm.state.persist_processor';
```

Instead of :

```php
RemoveProcessor::class;
PersistProcessor::class;
```